# Noun and Adjective Case Endings

Tags: падежи

Can someone help me figure out what do the letters outside and inside the brackets means? How do I read them?

http://www.russianforeveryone.com/Rufe/Lessons/Course1/Summary%20Tables/NounAdjective%20Endings_1.htm

Comment: Link is not enough, question is supposed to be self-sufficient. Links can get old. Please, modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

As it says under the table, "Soft variants of all endings are given in parenthesis."

Words can be either 'hard' (первый) or 'soft' (синий) meaning they consistently take either hard or soft endings:

`hard    soft
первый  синий
первого синего
первому синему
первым  синим
первом  синем`

There is also a 'mixed' class (e.g. лёгкий, большой) which is just like 'hard' except for endings whose fist letter is и/ы; in these cases they are 'soft', i.e. take the -и endings, not -ы:

`hard    soft   mixed
первый  синий  лёгкий
первого синего лёгкого
первому синему лёгкому
первым  синим  лёгким
первом  синем  лёгком`